# SIP Stack iPhone

Tags: iphone, sip

Does anyone have any docs/guides/code samples on implementing an SIP based IP or video connection on the iPhone?  I am looking for a place to start,  Google is not being friendly on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the pjsip library hosted on Google.
http://code.google.com/p/pjsip-iphone-audio-driver/

It's a stable, well-tested framework, used in production. Voalté generously donated the framework back into the OSS community. Robbie Hanson leads the project.

Comment: Thank you, do you know of an example that uses video?

Comment: I haven't seen anything that does video calls over SIP, yet.